# how to Publish an uwp application with sqlite database in it?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, uwp

when publishing the application and trying to access the database, the app crashes and nothing is saved. when i run in debug the changes (in debug run) are saved.
here is a different project i built to see if it works and it doesn't:

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="FDb" connectionString="Data Source=.\FDb.db;Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

a class for trying:

```
    public class Dog
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dog()
        {
            ID= 0;
        }
    }
```

the button event of the xaml page:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DogContext context = new DogContext();
        context.Dog.Add(new Dog() { Name = txtbxName.Text });
        List<Dog> Dogs = context.Dog.ToList();
        context.SaveChanges()
    }
```

i installed System.Data.SQLite and EF6 (i work in .net framework, not core)
tried to change the datasource directory in the connction string to different ones but i want to include it in the published app. i added the file to the solution explorer, changed the 'Build Action' to "Build" And changed 'Copy to output Directory' to "Copy if new". and in the project properties, under the publish settings i included the file as DataFile and 'required', and as 'include' with 'required'. i have a feeling im missing here an important stepbecause in debug it works only with full path but with relative path it only reads the data but doesnt save data.

thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the docs [Use a SQLite database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases)?This is the official tutorial for using SQLite database in UWP.

Comment: No, I haven't seen this... Thank you for sharing with me! This answers my question